# Eclipse error: "javaw.exe not found"

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7

I installed Python 2.7 recently and with it Django--as part of the installation I had to add a PATH environment variable with the path to my Python installation. 
After I did that, when I launch Eclipse, I get an error saying "javaw.exe" was not found. I need both Python and Eclipse on my machine, is there something I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed java runtime? If not, you need to install it first. If you have it already, you might need to adjust your path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

`java.exe`
Launch it with the following command

> \eclipse.exe -vm \bin\java.exe -vmargs -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote

Look at the `FAQ` section of [PyDev](http://pydev.org/faq.html)